# Laravel JOIN Problem with SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'album_id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have referenced other questions like mine, but I cannot figure out why I am getting the error in my example.

I have 3 table. nn_album , nn_song and pivot table nn_song_album_song

My table ID names are nn_album.album_id , nn_song.song_id , pivot table has id as a primary key and same column name "song_id" and "album_id"

I can add an album but when i want to add a new song to an album, I'm getting this error on save function...

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'album_id' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `album_id` from `nn_album` inner join `nn_song_album_song` on `nn_album`.`album_id` = `nn_song_album_song`.`album_id` where `nn_song_album_song`.`song_id` = 21)

My Song Model

```
public function albums()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Albums', 'nn_song_album_song', 'song_id', 'album_id');
}
```

My Album Model

```
public function songs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\SongDetail', 'nn_song_album_song', 'song_id', 'album_id');
}
```

My controller Save Function

```
$albums = request('albums');

if ($song_id>0)
{
    $entry = SongDetail::where('song_id', $song_id)->firstOrfail();
    $entry->update($data);
    $entry->albums()->sync($albums);
}
else
{
    $entry = SongDetail::create($data);
    $entry->albums()->attach($albums);
}
```

My View on Admin side for choose an album input (i can choose multiple album to add)

```
<div class="form-group form-float mainalbum" style="margin-bottom: 45px;border-bottom: solid 1px;">
    <div class="form-line">


        <select class="form-control show-tick" name="albums[]" id="albums" data-live-search="true" >

            @foreach($albums as $album)
                @if($album->album_id != 1)<option value="{{ $album->album_id }}" {{ collect(old('albums', $album))->contains($album->album_id) ? 'selected': '' }}>
                    {{ $album->album_name }}</option>@endif
            @endforeach


        </select>
        <select class="albums2" name="albums2[]" id="albums2" multiple>
            @foreach($albums as $album)
                @if($album->album_id != 1)<option value="{{ $album->album_id }}" {{ collect(old('albums', $album))->contains($album->album_id) ? 'selected': '' }}>
                    {{ $album->album_name }}</option>@endif
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

Do you have any idea what's going on here? What is my fault? If you share with me your thoughts, i appreciate you.

Thank you.

Comment: Well what the sql error message is pointing you to this that album_id exists in both tables but you are selecting album_id without specifying what one you want hence it is ambiguous

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your reply but how can i write this sql in my model on Laravel? Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Well you have really made things far more complicated than you need to, by naming everything against Laravel conventions. If this were set up as expected, you would have models named `Album` and `Song`, stored in database tables `albums` and `songs`, with a pivot table called `album_song`. Things would be much easier then.

But these conventions can be worked around if one [reads the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

> As mentioned previously, to determine the table name of the relationship's joining table, Eloquent will join the two related model names in alphabetical order. However, you are free to override this convention. You may do so by passing a second argument to the `belongsToMany` method.
>
> In addition to customizing the name of the joining table, you may also customize the column names of the keys on the table by passing additional arguments to the `belongsToMany` method. ***The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to.***

So, fixing your arguments we get:

```php
class SongDetail extends Model
{
    public function albums()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Albums', 'nn_song_album_song', 'song_id', 'album_id');
    }
}

class Albums extends Model
{
    public function songs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\SongDetail', 'nn_song_album_song', 'album_id', 'song_id');
    }
}
```

Which should define the relationship properly. Your controller again defies convention, as Laravel resource controllers typically define separate methods for storing and updating. But I can make one suggestion to clean up the code you've shown:

```php
$albums = request('albums');

try {
    $entry = SongDetail::findOrFail($song_id);
    $entry->update($data);
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    $entry = SongDetail::create($data);
}
$entry->albums()->sync($albums);
```

And in your view, if you want to pass an array of values you need to specify `multiple` on the `<select>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Well what the sql error message is pointing you to this that album_id exists in both tables but you are selecting album_id without specifying what one you want hence it is ambiguous

You can likely resolve this by instead specify the exact column on the line

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Albums', 'nn_song_album_song', 'song_id', 'album_id');
```

by changing it to

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Albums', 'nn_song_album_song', 'nn_song_album_song.song_id', 'nn_song_album_song.album_id');
```

I am not 100% on this solution as this is not the most familiar syntax to me but specifying the table for the output parameters should resolve the issue. You may need to apply tho to both models. The actual solution may be a variation of this but you will solve this by more specifically specifying table names for the fields in your queries using the dot syntax mentioned here and in other answers.

Answer (score -1):

When you joining two tables it joins column names also. You have to describe from which table you want to take album_id column. e.g. `nn_album.album_id` or `nn_song_album_song.album_id`

Your sql query has to look like this: `select nn_album.album_id from nn_album inner join nn_song_album_song on nn_album.album_id = nn_song_album_song.album_id where nn_song_album_song.song_id = 21`

Comment: Thanks Ramünas for your reply but how can i write this sql in my model on Laravel? Do you have an idea?